# iOS FBOpenGraphAction and taggable_friends

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-friends, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Does anyone know if i can use the tagging token (retrieved using taggable_friends graph api) to set the tags of a FBOpenGraphAction object?

Answer (score 0):

Believe this was answered in the Facebook Developers group, but for reference:

= tagging tokens should work when publishing Open Graph actions

= please file bugs here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/